# hibernate many-to-one association error

Tags: hibernate

I have two entities connected via a many-to-one relationship

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    public Long id;

    public String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    public Collection<B> b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=false)
    public A a;

    // ... some other members ...
}
```

Now I want to get all B's which have a "accepted" status of A:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class);
criteria.createAlias("a.status", "status");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "accepted"));
return criteria.list();
```

This cause hibernate to throw a "org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association: status". What I'm doing wrong? I thought the tables are associated because of the many-to-one relationship.

Comment: I think you got the Alias wrong. You cannot create alias on a property, you can create on association. See my updated answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On @ManyToOne you forgot to mention on which column it is joining on. provide a `@JoinColumn` and also specify mappedBy = 'a' / inverse = true etc.,

Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/)

**Update:**

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class,"b");
criteria.createAlias("b.a", "a");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("a.status", "accepted"));
return criteria.list();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer zeus, i edited my question and added your suggestions, but its not working with those changes too.